# Segmentation fault when using weave.inline

Tags: c++, python, scipy

I am new to embedding C++ code into Python. I am testing weave.inline. However I get a segmentation fault when running my code. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
from scipy import weave

def cpp_call(np_points):

assert(type(np_points) == type(1))

code = """
double z[np_points+1][np_points+1];

for (int x = 0; x <= np_points; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y <= np_points; y++)
    {
        z[x][y] = x*y;
    }
}
"""

return weave.inline(code,'np_points')
```

Comment: C++ code itself looks fine, if `np_points` is of type `int` and non-negative.
BTW you have a python indentation problem in your example.

Comment: What is your input, and what is the exact error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues here:

1) indention - your python function needs to be indented past the `def` line

2) your argument to the `weave.inline()` should be a list. See [here for details](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.weave.inline.html)

So the corrected code should look like:

```
from scipy import weave

def cpp_call(np_points):
  assert(type(np_points) == type(1))  
  code = """
  double z[np_points+1][np_points+1];

  for (int x = 0; x <= np_points; x++)
  {
    for (int y = 0; y <= np_points; y++)
    {
        z[x][y] = x*y;
    }
  }
  """ 
  return weave.inline(code,['np_points']) #Note the very important change here
```

This code runs fine for me.

Comment: Thanks Mike the [ ] for the list did the trick! I am however still not able to run the script for very large values of np_points. I still get a segmentation fault for np_points = 2000. My corresponding pure Python implementation can handle even larger values.